# Content is not reflecting in output file in resources folder eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I have used the below code to write the output to the file

```
URL res = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("resources/output.txt");
                    File file = Paths.get(res.toURI()).toFile();
                    System.out.println(file);
                    PrintWriter  writer = new PrintWriter (file);
                    writer.write(fileContent);
                    writer.close();

I am able to see the output in the windows file system(C:\dsassignment\ShortestPath\bin\resources\output.txt) but eclipse is not showing the output file content
```

Any help will be appreciable

Comment: You may need to use 'File > Refresh' to get Eclipse to pick up the changes.

Comment: Tried the option but still it is the same. I am not getting the output in eclipse resources folder

Comment: You are looking at 'bin\resources' (not just 'resources')? Project/Package Explorer usually hide the 'bin' directory